# What does $ tag mean in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

What does $ tag mean in Appcelerator? When I use this tag in any controller.js it works. But when I use it in libs js file I get error.

```
$.resetClass(someController, 'someClass')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ tag is the holder for a controller file. It is autogenerated by Titanium for every controller file.

Let's say you have these sets of files :
1 - index.xml, index.js, index.tss
2 - win.xml, win.js, win.tss
3 - dialog.xml, dialog.js, dialog.tss

So, $ is available for every .js file & it is the same thing which is returned by this:

***dialog.js***

```
var dollar = Alloy.createController('win');
// now dollar is exactly equal to ($ in win.js) & so does for other .js files.
```

---

In win.xml, suppose you have a topmost Window or View with an id='topView' & some internal child views lets say having ids = view1, view2, etc...

***win.xml***

```
<Alloy>
 <View id='topView'>
   <View id='view1'>
     <View id='view2'></View>
   </View>
 </View>
</Alloy>
```

now in win.js file, you can access these view ids like $.topView, $.view1, $.view2 & so on like this...

---

Finally in that **var dollar** code, you can access these ids from any other js file just like this:

```
var topView = dollar.topView;
var view1 = dollar.view1;
var view2 = dollar.view2;
```

---

To elaborate more, suppose you want to export some functionality from a controller to any other controller, you can do it this way:

***win.js***

```
$.methodNameToAccess = function () {alert('Kerberos!')};
```

---

here is the magic of exporting methods

***dialog.js***

```
dollar.methodNameToAccess();    // alerts your name :)
```

This was the basic guide what $ is and it's beyond that.. so it's your task now to explore it & use it efficiently.

Code Strong!

Comment: So when I apply your instruction, can I use like this dolar.resetClass(someController, 'someClass')?

Comment: definitely!.... dollar is exactly equal to the $ in its .js file.. you can everything with these two.